# Passing parameter value to a new form

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, devexpress

I would like to point to a row. 
Get the Oid(the parameter I want to pass). 
When I click a button on the ribbon. It will open MifarePasswordForm. I would like to pass Oid to MifarePasswordForm so that the Oid can be saved in Mifare Card but I'm stuck at getting the Oid. So far, this is what I've got.

```
public void barButtonItem1_ItemClick()
    {
        staff entity = gridView.GetRow(gridView.GetSelectedRows()[0]) as staff;
        entity.Oid;
        MifarePasswordForm modalForm = new MifarePasswordForm();
        modalForm.ShowDialog();
        RefreshData();
    }
```

This is my password form.

```
    public MifarePasswordForm(int _iD)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int iD = _iD;
    }
```

Updated code

```
      public void barButtonItem1_ItemClick()
    {
        staff entity = gridView.GetRow(gridView.GetSelectedRows()[0]) as staff;

        MifarePasswordForm modalForm = new MifarePasswordForm(entity.Oid);
        modalForm.ShowDialog();
        RefreshData();
    }

public MifarePasswordForm(int _iD)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int iD = _iD;
        textBox1.Text += iD;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: create an instance of form and pass as parameter in button click event. have you tried this?

Comment: can you give an example please?

Comment: MifarePasswordForm modalForm = new MifarePasswordForm(entity.Oid);

Comment: yes. I've done this right after I posted but I couldn't pass it to my password form

Comment: what does the `entity.Oid;`  line does alone there?

Comment: make your new form's public property and assign it from the base.

Comment: the single line of entity.Oid is an error. Then, i actually realized I have to place it in the parameter. So that was removed. I'll now try to assign from the base.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have manage to pass the value onto the password form. The bottom right textbox shows the Oid value.

Comment: @active92 pls accept the answer to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is, pass your parameter to form in the constructor itself OR, make a public property and access it after creating formInstance and assign it your designated value.

e.g.

```
MifarePasswordForm modalForm = new MifarePasswordForm(entity.Oid);
    modalForm.ShowDialog();
```